# how to add new method to TextBox Class

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

how to add new method   to TextBox Class 
i wont add new method to textbox.

like this

```
 txtname.Mymethod ();
```

can we do this ?
Thank you .

Comment: Choose the correct tag.

Comment: In c#, java or vb.net ?

Comment: You could create a class that derives from `TextBox` and then extend the class that way or you could define an extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for c#,you can create usercontrol for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Extension method for this like this.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void MyMethod(this TextBox txtBox)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static YourReturnType Mymethod(this TextBox txt, YourAdditionalArguments)
    {
    }
}
```